# Que select ya seleccionado, si lo vuelve a seleccionar que no sume

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Estoy desarrollando un programa que suma el tiempo de cada selection pero tiene un problema si el usuario vuelve a seleccionar el mismo selection que ya estaba seleccionado, vuelve a sumarse, y yo quiero que select ya seleccionado que no cuenten mas

```
    <form method="post" id="formulario">
    
                    <label for="spam">Vaciar SPAM</label>
                    <select class="seleccionTiempos">
                        <option value="0">0 min</option>
                        <option value="15">15 min</option>
                        <option value="30">30 min</option>
                        <option value="45">45 min</option>
                        <option value="60">1 hora</option>
                    </select>
<br><br>
                <label for="netflix">Buscar pelis en Netflix </label>
                <select class="seleccionTiempos">
                    <option value="0">0 min</option>
                    <option value="15">15 min</option>
                    <option value="30">30 min</option>
                    <option value="45">45 min</option>
                    <option value="60">1 hora</option>
                </select>
     <button id="pagEventos">Restar tiempo</button>
                </form>
    
                <br />
                Tiempo total: <spam id="resultado">0</spam>
    
        <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            var sumTotal = 0
            $("select.seleccionTiempos").change(function() {
    
    
                var selectedTiempo = parseInt($(this).children("option:selected").val(), 10)
                sumTotal+=selectedTiempo
    
                $( "#resultado" ).empty()
                $("#resultado").append(sumTotal)
    
            });
        });
        </script>
```

Comment: Crea un arreglo, y guarda el valor de cada option. Antes de hacer la insercion comprueba si ya existe; si existe lo ignora, sino, lo inserta. Al final lo que muestras como contador es el length de ese arreglo

Comment: me podrias guiar un poco con codigo? porfavor, grcias

Comment: como podría comprobar que existe ? si solo guardo en el arreglo ¿¿¿numeros???

Comment: Puedes hacer:
Arreglo.includes(VALOR) y asi comprubas si existe o no. Luego haces $("#resultado").append(Arreglo.length)

Answer (score 0):

Eso lo puedes solucionar desahabilitando el select, para ello debes añadir la siguiente línea.

```
$(this).attr("disabled", true);
```

Tu script quedaría así.

```
<form method="post" id="formulario">

                <label for="spam">Vaciar SPAM</label>
                <select class="seleccionTiempos">
                    <option value="0">0 min</option>
                    <option value="15">15 min</option>
                    <option value="30">30 min</option>
                    <option value="45">45 min</option>
                    <option value="60">1 hora</option>
                </select>
            <label for="netflix">Buscar pelis en Netflix </label>
            <select class="seleccionTiempos">
                <option value="0">0 min</option>
                <option value="15">15 min</option>
                <option value="30">30 min</option>
                <option value="45">45 min</option>
                <option value="60">1 hora</option>
            </select>
 <button id="pagEventos">Restar tiempo</button>
            </form>

            <br />
            Tiempo total: <spam id="resultado">0</spam>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var sumTotal = 0
        $("select.seleccionTiempos").change(function() {


            var selectedTiempo = parseInt($(this).children("option:selected").val(), 10)
            sumTotal+=selectedTiempo

            $( "#resultado" ).empty()
            $("#resultado").append(sumTotal)
            $(this).attr("disabled", true);

        });
    });
    </script>
```

Espero que fuese lo que buscabas.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacerlo de una forma sencilla, como lo estás haciendo con la misma clase, únicamente hacemos un ciclo `each` para recorrer los valores y los sumamos y para la prueba ya con él `alert` muestro el resultado de la suma.

```js
$(".seleccionTiempos").change(function() {
    var sum = 0.0;
    $('.seleccionTiempos').each(function()
    {
        sum += parseFloat($(this).val());
    });
    alert(sum);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label for="spam">Vaciar SPAM</label>
<select class="seleccionTiempos">
    <option value="0">0 min</option>
    <option value="15">15 min</option>
    <option value="30">30 min</option>
    <option value="45">45 min</option>
    <option value="60">1 hora</option>
</select>
<br><br>
<label for="netflix">Buscar pelis en Netflix </label>
<select class="seleccionTiempos">
    <option value="0">0 min</option>
    <option value="15">15 min</option>
    <option value="30">30 min</option>
    <option value="45">45 min</option>
    <option value="60">1 hora</option>
</select>
```